# jQuery use $(document).click event as a 'cancel selection' event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, events

I'm building an app.net page using jQuery for DOM manipulation ([JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/thewizarodofoz/qkx2o330/)). When I click a certain `<td>` on the table it becomes target for future manipulation. I want to add code, so that a click anywhere outside the table will un-target that `<td>` (meaning a click in the background should act as a cancel selection event).

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element) did not help me, because:
A. I don't want to use `stopPropagation()` because of [this article](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/) plus I have many click event handlers in my code that I will have to stop from propagating).
B. I have other elements on the page (buttons, text-input fields) which should NOT act as a cancel selection event).

Comment: it would really help if you only leave the summary from your question, and replace that whole unnecessary wall of text with a working example and a link to the other discussion that you have mentioned.

Comment: edited my question... thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more specifics it seems like toggling an active class on target cells would do what you are suggesting.

```
var $table = $('#myTable').on('click', 'td', function(){
    $table.find('.active').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Then for removing using events outside table just check if target is in the table

```
$(document).click(function(e){
  if(!$(e.target).closest('#myTable').length){
      $table.find('active').removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. I tried this, but as I mentioned - I have other elements on my page (button and text fields) and I do not want them to trigger `removeClass`.

Comment: Then you need to provide a lot more detail in the form of sample html...in a demo....jsfiddle.net, plnkr.co etc. Could also exclude clicks on form as target

Comment: added JSFiddle with all the neccesary data.

Comment: OK ...added one extra selector in `closest()` ....https://jsfiddle.net/nLLw0why/ could narrow that down more to `#container :input, #container button` also

Comment: thanks! didn't know it was possible to reference multiple selectors like that.